# R How to combine two matrices by row name when they have different numbers of rows

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two matrices, note the dates are Characters and are actually the column and row names

I'd like to combine them, but they are different sizes (i.e. I want to put them side by side)

matrix A:

```
    04/06/2012  11/06/2012
26/03/2012  10  11
02/04/2012  9   10
09/04/2012  8   9
16/04/2012  7   8
23/04/2012  6   7
30/04/2012  5   6
```

matrix B:

```
    18/06/2012  25/06/2012
26/03/2012  12  13
02/04/2012  11  12
09/04/2012  10  11
16/04/2012  9   10
23/04/2012  8   9
30/04/2012  7   8
07/05/2012  6   7
14/05/2012  5   6
21/05/2012  4   5
28/05/2012  3   4
```

Desired output:

```
    04/06/2012  11/06/2012  18/06/2012  25/06/2012
26/03/2012  10  11  12  13
02/04/2012  9   10  11  12
09/04/2012  8   9   10  11
16/04/2012  7   8   9   10
23/04/2012  6   7   8   9
30/04/2012  5   6   7   8
07/05/2012  NA  NA  6   7
14/05/2012  NA  NA  5   6
21/05/2012  NA  NA  4   5
28/05/2012  NA  NA  3   4
```

I'd like to keep it as a matrix format

Comment: have you tried the merge command or the sqldf command from the sqldf package? the later uses sql syntax if you're comfortable with that.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Since the row names of `A` are a subset of the row names of `B` we can first merge them by row name creating `m` and then reorder the rows according to `B` creating `m2`.  We also drop the `Row.names` column that `merge` creates.  Lastly we transfer the rownames of `B` to `m2`:

```
m <- merge(A, B, by = 0, all = TRUE)
m2 <- m[match(rownames(B), m[, "Row.names"]), -1]
rownames(m2) <- rownames(B)
```

giving:

```
> m2
           04/06/2012 11/06/2012 18/06/2012 25/06/2012
26/03/2012         10         11         12         13
02/04/2012          9         10         11         12
09/04/2012          8          9         10         11
16/04/2012          7          8          9         10
23/04/2012          6          7          8          9
30/04/2012          5          6          7          8
07/05/2012         NA         NA          6          7
14/05/2012         NA         NA          5          6
21/05/2012         NA         NA          4          5
28/05/2012         NA         NA          3          4
```

**1a)** Realizing that the real problem is the fact that the row names are not in a representation that does not sort properly, if we reformat the dates so that they do sort this can be simplified to just a merge.  `merge` creates a data.frame with a `Row.names` column which we change back to a matrix:

```
# reformat Dates so that they sort
refmt <- function(x) format(as.Date(chartr(".", "/", x), "%d/%m/%Y"))
A2 <- A; dimnames(A2) <- lapply(dimnames(A2), refmt)
B2 <- B; dimnames(B2) <- lapply(dimnames(B2), refmt)

ABdf <- merge(A2, B2, by = 0, all = TRUE, suffixes = "")

# convert back to matrix
AB <- as.matrix(ABdf[, -1])
rownames(AB) <- ABdf$Row.names
```

giving:

```
> AB
           2012-06-04 2012-06-11 2012-06-18 2012-06-25
2012-03-26         10         11         12         13
2012-04-02          9         10         11         12
2012-04-09          8          9         10         11
2012-04-16          7          8          9         10
2012-04-23          6          7          8          9
2012-04-30          5          6          7          8
2012-05-07         NA         NA          6          7
2012-05-14         NA         NA          5          6
2012-05-21         NA         NA          4          5
2012-05-28         NA         NA          3          4
```

**2)** Another way would be convert the matrices to zoo objects, merge them and make nicer column names:

```
library(zoo)
fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
Az <- zoo(A, as.Date(rownames(A), fmt))
Bz <- zoo(A, as.Date(rownames(B), fmt))

ABz <- merge(Az, Bz, all = TRUE)

# optionally make nicer column dates
colnames(ABz) <- format(as.Date(c(colnames(Az), colnames(Bz)), "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

giving the zoo object:

```
> ABz
           2012-06-04 2012-06-11 2012-06-04 2012-06-11
2012-03-26         10         11         10         11
2012-04-02          9         10          9         10
2012-04-09          8          9          8          9
2012-04-16          7          8          7          8
2012-04-23          6          7          6          7
2012-04-30          5          6          5          6
2012-05-07         NA         NA         10         11
2012-05-14         NA         NA          9         10
2012-05-21         NA         NA          8          9
2012-05-28         NA         NA          7          8
```

This could optionally be turned back into a matrix like this:

```
m <- coredata(ABz)
rownames(m) <- format(time(ABz))
```

although we might just want to keep it as a zoo object to facilitate other time series operations.

**Update** Added 1a and 2.  Other improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate question: [Concatenating Matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324833/concatenating-matrices-in-r)

more info about rbind and cbind: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cbind.html

Comment: this works assuming that the matrices first columns are equivalent up until a certain point. if they are different then binding won't return the desired result.

Comment: Second answer `gdata::cbindx` works. We must find a Hadley solution for this problem. If there isn't one, he is obviously slacking...