# join multiple matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to join several matrix in R, with [48 39 920] dimensions in one single multiarrays [48 39 920 nx], nx is the number of my matrix. For that I am using abind, but I have some problem to get the right dimensions. This is what I am trying:

```
  matvar <- sapply (1:length(vars), function (i) {
         abind(vars[[i]],along=4)
          })
```

The final dimension for matvar is [1722240  26] , which means 48*39*920...but I want [48 39 920 26]...I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe start with a nice small (reproducible) example and see what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324833/concatenating-matrices-in-r
This link might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
library(magic)
do.call(adiag, replicate(100, x, simplify = FALSE))
```

Here, nx = 100